# Passing an array to sort in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Say I have an array consisting of lines such as:

```
arr[0] = 20160330        asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
arr[1] = 20140102        asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
arr[2] = 20160306        dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
```

I now want to sort them by the first column, and print the them in the sorted order:

```
20140102        asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
20160306        dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
20160330        asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```

How do I use sort on an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that none of the array elements contain newline characters, then try:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -nk1,1
20140102        asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
20160306        dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
20160330        asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```

#### Sorting and then removing the first number

Using cut:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -nk1,1 | cut -d" " -f2-
       asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
       dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
       asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```

Using sed:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -nk1,1 | sed 's/[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*//'
asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```

Comment: Is it only possible to cut the first numbers so that the lines would start as: `asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014`, etc..

Comment: @LamaEu Yes,  I just added two methods for removing the leading number.

Comment: Hey, John. This doens't seem to work.` $ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -nk1,1 | cut -d" " -f2-` did not cut the first column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use process substitution with `printf`:

```
sort -nk1 <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")

20140102        asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
20160306        dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
20160330        asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```